# Facebook API: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later

Tags: python, facebook

I'm getting this error when trying to publish to a Facebook page with the Python facebook-sdk:

> An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.

Here's the code:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
fbpages = graph.request('me/accounts')
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(fbpages['data'][0]['access_token'])
graph.put_object(fbpages['data'][0]['id'], "feed", message="My test message")
```

I'm using the Python facebook-sdk found here: https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk.

[edit]

I should also note that after further testing I've noticed that this problem is only occurring on the test accounts associated with the Facebook application. When using my personal account, which has the role of developer, the above code works.

Comment: did you retry your request later?

Comment: Yes. The problem has been occurring for the past two days.

Comment: from time to time i have same issue.

Comment: @Neara Strangely it turned out that I was only getting this problem with the Facebook 'Test Users' accounts. The code worked fine when posting to a normal user's page.

Comment: @user2547755 for me it happens when i use applicatin access token

Comment: @Neara I'm sorry I can't help as I never had to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

this problem also occurs when the target page is denying the authorization to post on it.

SOLUTION:

go to the target page settings and allow the option "allow other persons to publish on this page".

https://www.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE/settings?tab=settings&section=posting_ability&view